# Function to add prefix based on category does not work for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Event participations are being sold on the website. Every order can contain 1 product (qty is variable). Based on the main category of the products that is being sold, a prefix is added to the ordernumber for administration purposes.

Now we have a new, variable product(!), which has the main cat 'example-4' assigned. When adding this to our existing code, all prefixes are working fine except the one for the variable product.

I already edited the original code to take in account these product variatons but it doesnt work. The website still assigns the prefixed for simple product orders but not for for orders with the variation product:

```
function filter_woocommerce_order_number( $order_number, $order ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Product ID
        $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();

        // Has term (product category)
        if ( has_term( array( 'example-1', 'example-2', 'example-3', 'example-4' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            return 'UF-' . $order_number;
        }
        elseif ( has_term( array( 'example-5' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            return 'UH-' . $order_number;
        }
        elseif ( has_term( array( 'example-6' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            return 'UT-' . $order_number;
        }
        elseif ( has_term( array( 'example-7' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            return 'HP-' . $order_number;
        } //This is the prefix that should be assignd to orders with the variaton product

    }
    
    return $order_number;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'filter_woocommerce_order_number', 10, 2 );
```

I already changed the code so it takes the product varation type into considering but doesnt work. Openai didnt manage to solve it as well.

Comment: It wont take my entire code into the code editor but you get the idea

Comment: Have you first of all verified that it actually gets the correct product ID, in case you are dealing with a variation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the category to check for a product variation as categories apply to the parent product, not the variation. The following should work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', function( $order_number, $order ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if ( ! empty( $product_id = $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
            $order_number = has_term( array( 'example-1', 'example-2', 'example-3', 'example-4' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ? 'UF-' . $order_number : $order_number;
            $order_number = has_term( array( 'example-5' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ? 'UH-' . $order_number : $order_number;
            $order_number = has_term( array( 'example-6' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ? 'UT-' . $order_number : $order_number;
            $order_number = has_term( array( 'example-7' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ? 'HP-' . $order_number : $order_number;
        }
    }
    return $order_number;
}, 10, 2 );
```